# How to start GETH console?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, geth-debugging

I'm getting the following:

```
➜  voting_truffle geth console
WARN [11-29|22:53:43] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another process
```

But it seems like I could get into the console using `geth attach`:

```
➜  voting_truffle geth attach
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 64827,
  highestBlock: 4644478,
  knownStates: 43977,
  pulledStates: 41202,
  startingBlock: 0
}
>
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is that `voting_truffle geth console` tries to start a new geth instance and use the already in use port and when you use attach, you just connect a new terminal to the already running geth instance.